# jQueryUI dialog modal background with Google's CDN

Tags: css, jquery-ui, cdn, google-cdn

I previously downloaded jQueryUI at http://jqueryui.com/download/ and used all the default settings.  The background of the dialog had the below appearance:

[image]

The top of the original CSS file included the following:

```
/*! jQuery UI - v1.11.3 - 2015-03-02
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: core.css, draggable.css, resizable.css, selectable.css, sortable.css, accordion.css, autocomplete.css, button.css, datepicker.css, dialog.css, menu.css, progressbar.css, selectmenu.css, slider.css, spinner.css, tabs.css, tooltip.css, theme.css
* To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Trebuchet%20MS%2CTahoma%2CVerdana%2CArial%2Csans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=4px&bgColorHeader=f6a828&bgTextureHeader=gloss_wave&bgImgOpacityHeader=35&borderColorHeader=e78f08&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=eeeeee&bgTextureContent=highlight_soft&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=dddddd&fcContent=333333&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=f6f6f6&bgTextureDefault=glass&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=cccccc&fcDefault=1c94c4&iconColorDefault=ef8c08&bgColorHover=fdf5ce&bgTextureHover=glass&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=fbcb09&fcHover=c77405&iconColorHover=ef8c08&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=glass&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=fbd850&fcActive=eb8f00&iconColorActive=ef8c08&bgColorHighlight=ffe45c&bgTextureHighlight=highlight_soft&bgImgOpacityHighlight=75&borderColorHighlight=fed22f&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=228ef1&bgColorError=b81900&bgTextureError=diagonals_thick&bgImgOpacityError=18&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=ffd27a&bgColorOverlay=666666&bgTextureOverlay=diagonals_thick&bgImgOpacityOverlay=20&opacityOverlay=50&bgColorShadow=000000&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgImgOpacityShadow=10&opacityShadow=20&thicknessShadow=5px&offsetTopShadow=-5px&offsetLeftShadow=-5px&cornerRadiusShadow=5px
* Copyright 2015 jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */
```

I've since started using Google's CDN (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryui) and now there is no modal stripped background.  The top of the CSS file includes the following, and there are other differences as well.  How can I use Google's CDN yet obtain the original appearance?

```
/*! jQuery UI - v1.11.3 - 2015-02-12
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: core.css, accordion.css, autocomplete.css, button.css, datepicker.css, dialog.css, draggable.css, menu.css, progressbar.css, resizable.css, selectable.css, selectmenu.css, slider.css, sortable.css, spinner.css, tabs.css, tooltip.css, theme.css
* To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Verdana%2CArial%2Csans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=4px&bgColorHeader=cccccc&bgTextureHeader=highlight_soft&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&borderColorHeader=aaaaaa&fcHeader=222222&iconColorHeader=222222&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=flat&bgImgOpacityContent=75&borderColorContent=aaaaaa&fcContent=222222&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=e6e6e6&bgTextureDefault=glass&bgImgOpacityDefault=75&borderColorDefault=d3d3d3&fcDefault=555555&iconColorDefault=888888&bgColorHover=dadada&bgTextureHover=glass&bgImgOpacityHover=75&borderColorHover=999999&fcHover=212121&iconColorHover=454545&bgColorActive=ffffff&bgTextureActive=glass&bgImgOpacityActive=65&borderColorActive=aaaaaa&fcActive=212121&iconColorActive=454545&bgColorHighlight=fbf9ee&bgTextureHighlight=glass&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcefa1&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=fef1ec&bgTextureError=glass&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=cd0a0a&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=flat&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px
* Copyright 2015 jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */
```

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example? Trying to determine how the modal overlay changed between versions just from the header comment would be pure speculation at best

Comment: @blgt.  I think the approach is to determine what the CDN version includes and what the default download includes, and add the difference as a separate file hosted locally.  I just don't know how to determine the difference.

Comment: I have just downloaded the *.zip of jQuery UI v1.11.3, from [February 2015] (http://blog.jqueryui.com/2015/02). The only resource from [March 2015] (http://blog.jqueryui.com/2015/03) is the v1.11.4. It's very strange that your original CSS said v1.11.3 - 2015-03-02. Mine says v1.11.3 - 2015-02-12. I would say there's something peculiar with your original rather than the one hosted by Cloud CDN. I am afraid your question has no answer, only if you want to use and have cached **your** version of the jQuery UI library, instead of the hosted one.